# Collect method is taking longer in spark when deployed in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I have been trying to deploy spark and jupyter note on minikube.  I used helm charts for deploying both

Jupyter notebook - https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/pyspark-notebook-helm/pyspark-notebook

Spark - https://bitnami.com/stack/spark/helm

While able to establish to the master using

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://my-release-spark-master-0.my-release-spark-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:7077").getOrCreate()
```

When running the following snippet

```
nums= sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
squared = nums.map(lambda x: x*x).collect()
for num in squared:
    print('%i ' % (num))
```

The execution takes a long time and never completes when it runs the collect() method

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [prerequisites](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#prerequisites) when running Spark in Kubernetes to determine if it will increase its performance


A running Kubernetes cluster at version >= 1.22 with access configured to it using [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/prereqs/). If you do not already have a working Kubernetes cluster, you may set up a test cluster on your local machine using [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/).



We recommend using the latest release of minikube with the DNS addon enabled.


Be aware that the default minikube configuration is not enough for running Spark applications. We recommend 3 CPUs and 4g of memory to be able to start a simple Spark application with a single executor.


Check [kubernetes-client library](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client)’s version of your Spark environment, and its compatibility with your Kubernetes cluster’s version.



You must have appropriate permissions to list, create, edit and delete [pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/) in your cluster. You can verify that you can list these resources by running 


     kubectl auth can-i <list|create|edit|delete> pods


The service account credentials used by the driver pods must be allowed to create pods, services and configmaps.


You must have [Kubernetes DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) configured in your cluster.